# C# Mail Server?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to understand exactly what it is I need to be implementing and am just after a little guidance. I know very little about email standards such as POP3, IMAP, SMTP which is probably what's making the getting started difficult.

What'd I'd like to do consists of a couple of things:

1. Be notified of the arrival of an email at a specific custom address. e.g. hi.me@myapp.com.
2. Handle multiple addresses per user.
3. Be able to process this email and either delete it, leave it and be able to display in a web email client or forward it on based on various rules.

I've seen a few SMTP libraries and a POP3 one, but I'm not 100% sure what I need to do this. I'm guessing the best way would be to write a full C# mail server - but I'm hoping for a little guidance/suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: You want to build a MTA ? Best is to start reading up on all mail RFCs. (My advice is: don't write a complete mail server; they exist and can be quite complex. Use an existing MTA and just write a C# program that will poll the inbox)

Comment: "I don't know much about mechanical engineering but I'd like to re-invent the wheel". If you really insist you need to do this why not check out a few open source projects in that field? Sorry if my comment sounds a bit harsh but someone with your experience should know better.

Comment: @Filburt: I'm not sure I do need to re-invent it, I certainly don't want to. At the minute I guess I don't understand them enough - barts comment referring to an 'MTA' already gives me something to at least google. I believe your traditional mail server would have a single email bob@test.com for a particular account that you can connect to. Whereas I want bob.work@test.com and bob.home@test.com all rolled into a single account. I don't know if a traditional mail server can do that and at the moment I'm at a loss what to read up on.

Comment: What scale are you aiming for? Is this solution intended for a couple of users or are you trying to build something enterprise or SaaS sized?

Comment: @MarnixvanValen: It's just an idea at the moment, but if it were to work the idea would be SaaS. I wanted to try and mock something up, get a feel for how it would work and see if it would have traction, but I think I need to learn some stuff about mail servers first. Be interested to know what it is you've worked on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to build a mailserver from scratch, the protocol specifications are all available as RFCs.

For IMAP that would be [RFC-3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501) and for SMTP [RFC-2821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt), you can google for the rest.

I've been working on a C# SMTP server in my (very limited) spare time, mostly out of frustration with existing MTAs and as an exercise in C# server programming. I can tell you that there's a bit more to it than you might think. So if you want fast results, I'd seriously consider hooking into an existing MTA/mailserver setup.

Depending on how fast you want to process messages, it may be sufficient to poll one or more mailboxes. You could process the messages and, for example, forward them to another mailbox using the built-in .NET [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).

On top of that, all mail servers I know of implement not just the SMTP protocol but also a slew of anti-spam measures. Most of these measures have matured over many years. You get all that for free if you build on top of an existing mail server infrastructure.

Then again, configuration of just about any mail server I know seems to be a fine art, hence my frustration with them.

Comment: I've been having a look and found some MTA's that seem to have the capabilities I'd like (all seem unix based) so then I need to see if I can figure out a way to hook in some C# processing whenever a new mail is received.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can hook up custom code over a TCP socket with Postfix (see api [here](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_POLICY_README.html) and more info [here](http://www.arschkrebs.de/slides/maps_policyd.pdf)). That may be a nice way to hook the mail server up to a C# service running on another box (or Mono).

Comment: I've had a look at post fix and while I don't understand much of their documentation it does look like post fix or something similar would be the best tool for the job. It looks rather daunting before I even get into the interesting stuff, so best get learning. Thanks